# Asking a question that was already asked but answered?

Tags: support, bump

I want to ask exactly [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1149178/make-windows-10-always-accept-bluetooth-files) question but it since it's already there I can't ask it again. I know commenting on it doesn't bump it, but I want to make it visible again, how can this be done?

Comment: Since it has no answer, your question could not be closed as a duplicate, I would ask a better question though.  There are numerous reasons that question wasn’t answered.